# Pandas Assigning back a series that was filtered with notnull()

Tags: python, pandas, series

Hello fellow developers,

I am currently learning pandas and still trying to wrap my head around how to assign values, that I converted to a specific type for example, back to the origin dataframe.

More specific I have this dataframe:

```
     id         A       B
0   50000    12413     32885.0
1   50001     2040     43737.0
3   50002     2040     28015.0
4   50003     2040      NaN
5   50004     2040     28565.0
```

My goal is to convert column `B` to integers but leave `NaN` values as is, so no `fillna(0)`. I want to have this:

```
     id         A       B
0   50000    12413     32885
1   50001     2040     43737
3   50002     2040     28015
4   50003     2040      NaN
5   50004     2040     28565
```

I did this with
    `print(df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'].astype('int'))`
and it worked.

```
        B
0   32885
1   43737
3   28015
4   28565
```

But if I try to assign it back to the data frame whith:

```
df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'] = df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'].astype('int')
```

I still get the original, unconverted data. So I seem to do the assignment wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.
Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With pandas, avoid combining `NaN` with integers**

Unless you have an extremely good reason, avoid this practice. The reason is `pandas` only allows vectorised computations with arrays in contiguous memory blocks. This is only possible with data of the same type, e.g. a series of type `int`, `float`, `datetime`, but *not* `object`.

`NaN` is considered `float`. Therefore, combining integers with `NaN` forces `pandas` to, by default, upcast the entire series to `float`. This increases memory usage, but for most use cases is not an issue.

If you wish to combine `NaN` with integers, you need to create a series with `dtype=object`, and have `pandas` work with a series of pointers. This is expensive computationally and memory-intensive. Do not do it unless you absolutely must.

**But if you simply must...**

You can convert a series to `object` before converting non-`NaN` elements to integers:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(object)
```

As explained above, you are asking `pandas` / `numpy` to work with a pointer for each item in your series. You might as well start working with lists instead.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation. The problem is, the input is out of my control. Its a large excel file exported from a system. So I have to account for the fact that there will be missing values. I would love an easy way to tell pandas "ignore the NaNs and display the floats as integers". But only for certain columns, because some columns need to be float. I tried with to_csv(...float_format='%.f') but then all columns become ints.

Comment: @BenjaminBode, Sure, if this is just a step to get the right format in Excel at the end of your process, using `object` may be an easy win. Just remember to do this as a *final* step once you have completed all your computations.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of `object` columns as series of pointers, that's a useful way to think about it.

Comment: @IanS, Yes. Often I see people talk about "vectorising" string-based operations in `pandas` with `object` series. This is usually *slower* than simple list comprehensions since you are working with pointers in both, but `pandas` has an additional overhead.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that either :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `type(np.nan)` is `float`, you need to convert the type of your column first. For example, you can do

```
df['B'] = df.B.astype(object)
df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'] = df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'].astype('int')
```

Note that this may have a negative impact on memory usage and performance.

Comment: It worked, thanks. So you mean it doesn't have to do with the assignment itself, but with the fact that pandas converts the column back to float because NaN is still there?